# Write SQL result/record directly to another database?

Tags: sql, vbscript, intersystems-cache

I have the following script that reads records from a database successfully:

```
sDSN = MyDSN
sUsername = username
sPassword = password
sSQL ="Select TOP 1 * myTable"
sDSN = "DSN=" & sDSN & ";UID=" & sUsername & ";PWD=" & sPassword & ";"
Set sConnect = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
WScript.Echo "Opening connection to source..."
sConnect.Open sDSN
Set resultSet = sConnect.Execute(sSQL)

On Error Resume Next
resultSet.MoveFirst
Do While Not resultSet.eof
  WScript.Echo resultSet("ID") & "," & resultSet("SomeColumn") & "," & resultSet("SomeOtherColumn")
  resultSet.MoveNext
Loop
resultSet.Close
sConnect.Close
Set sConnect = Nothing
```

This works great and outputs something like the following:

> 1,value,value2

So what I want to do is write this back to another database.  I realize I could manually write a query that specifies each column, but I'm wondering if there is some way to just insert the `resultset()` in one easy command.

Does anyone know if this is possible?  It's CACHÉ since someone always asks :)

Answer (score 1):

In VBScript, no there is no easy way.  I am not sure what CACHE is or does, so that doesn't factor into my answer.

What you will need to do is build the text for the insert query on each loop of the result set.

```
dim InsertSQL = "insert into MyNewTable values (" & resultSet("ID") & "," & resultSet("SomeColumn") & ")"
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm doing.  It just sucks because I plan to do this on multiple tables and that means I'll have to modify the script for each.  I guess I could get the length of the resultSet and do a nested loop?

Comment: The only way to improve would be to use the Information Schema table and do some real work to setup a generic DB-to-DB program.  The other option is to get into .NET.  Then you might be able to use data adapters and tables to do this with less column name typing.  Here is a link to get you started; it only dumps to CSV, but might work.  http://greaterthancomputing.blogspot.com/2014/02/export-entire-database-to-csv-text.html

Answer (score 1):

If nobody has a better answer, this works fairly well and is reusable regardless of the table

```
  tSQL = "INSERT INTO targetTable VALUES ("
  For i = 0 To resultSet.fields.Count
     tSQL = tSQL & resultSet(i)
     if i <> resultSet.fields.Count Then 
        tSQL = tSQL & ","
     end if
  Next
  tSQL = tSQL & ")"
```

Comment: Ah, very good.  That keeps you from having to type of column names.

Comment: Unfortunately now I realize I can't use parameters so I have some significant data validation problems with single quotes and commas in fields :(

Comment: Yes, those are all issues with VBScript and database programming.  Probably not acceptable, but you can write a simple function to strip out all the offending characters.  That's what I used to do for some non-sensitive apps (such as email notifications and such).